# What is the best way to populate a data-bound property from an async method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have a simple requirement I am trying to achieve. Basically I have a view that gets populates with a list of businesses. The property for the list of businesses is embodied in my viewmodel class which in turn is bound to the view. This is a simple MVC application with a list of business.

However, the issue I have is that I derive the list of business for another class which is a dependency to the view model, and its basically similar to a repository which I call BusinessService. Busy service is comprised of async methods and this is the dilemma I have, when the call is made from the Ctor of the viewModel or the getter of the property, my application hangs. The call is to a EF database asynchrounous too within the businessservice and am not sure what is the correct approach for this. Please see code below:

ViewModel:

```
    #region Ctor

    public BusinessListViewModel(IBusinessService businessService, IStringBuilder builder)
    {
        _businessService = businessService;
        _builder = builder;

        InitBusinesses().Wait(); //OPTION 1
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public IEnumerable<BusinessViewModel> _businesses;
    public IEnumerable<BusinessViewModel> Businesses
    {
        get
        {
            if (_businesses == null)
            {
                InitBusinesses().Wait(); //OPTION 2
            }
            return _businesses;
        }
        set => _businesses = value;
    }

    private async Task InitBusinesses()
    {
        var response = await _businessService.Get();
        Businesses = response.IsSuccessful 
                            ? response.Data.Select(p => new BusinessViewModel(_builder, p)) 
                            : new List<BusinessViewModel>();
    }
```

BUSINESS SERVICE:

```
    #region Service Methods

    public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<Models.Business>>> Get()
    {
        var data = await Db.Businesses.ToListAsync();
        return new Response<IEnumerable<Models.Business>>
        {
            IsSuccessful = true,
            Message = "Successful",
            Data = Mapper.Map<List<Models.Business>>(data)
        };
    }
```

Please may you advise the best pattern and the correct way to do this, I already know this is wrong> Thank you

Comment: Neither of the options you asked about are good. Properties should not load data. Methods should load data. Properties should contain information about the object, not be a means of loading data from other sources. Maintain a distinct separation between the data designed to encapsulate information (models) from the logic designed to retrieve that information (data layer)

Comment: @mason Thank you for your reply, as stated, I already understand that it is not the correct way. Even using the Unit of Work & Repository pattern, how would you populate your property to bind to the user interface, according to your explanation?

Comment: Don't have the view model do it. Have the code outside do it. It usually looks something like `var myViewModel = new MyViewModel(); myViewModel.Businesses = await _repository.GetBusinessesAsync();`

Comment: @mason Precisely where I was going wrong, I was trying to keep my controller as thin as possibly, but I think this way makes the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an [article on the subject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

When the UI framework asks your code to display something, it must be displayed immediately (synchronously). ViewModel constructors and data-bound properties should be synchronous and immediate. Doing network I/O is simply not an option; even if you got it working (which is possible), all that would do is block your UI thread, degrading your user experience.

A more proper solution is to synchronously *initialize* into a loading state ("Loading..." message, spinner, whatever) and also start the asynchronous operation. Then, when the operation completes, *update* the UI with the actual data.

Comment: @JohnWu: Sorry, I missed that this was ASP.NET. MVC doesn't use data binding; the MVC way to do this is to have the controller asynchronously load all the data and then set the properties on the ViewModel. In MVC, ViewModels shouldn't be loading their own data; that's the responsibility of the controller.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thank you for your assistance. I understand now, with all the examples online, people do it in varying ways and at times a ViewModel loses its meaning and it does more. What I elect to do is inject the BusinessService into the Controller to do the heavy lifting and populate the ViewModel. Like mentioned to by Daniel below, I need not inject the viewmodel but instantiate within and populate. Shot

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a factory method that returns a `Task`

```
private BusinessListViewModel(IBusinessService businessService, IStringBuilder builder)
{
    _businessService = businessService;
    _builder = builder;
}

public static async Task<BusinessListViewModel> Create(IBusinessService businessService, IStringBuilder builder)
{
    var instance = new BusinessListViewModel(businessService, builder)
    await InitBusiness();
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Either use dependency injection or by interface contract. Based on your example using both doesn’t make any sense